# Find partitions before a certain date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've been requested to find all partitions of a table before a certain date, the script will rerun everyday and delete all partitions 60 days created more than 60 days ago.
I've come up with this script that tries to find the number of partitions to delete and save it on a properties table for later use.

```
DECLARE
  numero_di_partizioni NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numero_di_partizioni
  FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CA_LG_SATELLITI_IMEL'
    AND PARTITION_NAME LIKE 'SYS%'
    AND TO_DATE(SUBSTR(HIGH_VALUE, INSTR(HIGH_VALUE, '''')+2, 19), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') < sysdate - 60 ;

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO IML_PA_PROPERTY (PR_KEY, PR_VALUE)
    VALUES ('DROP_PART_TO_CA_LG_SATELLITI_IMEL', numero_di_partizioni);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
      UPDATE IML_PA_PROPERTY
      SET PR_VALUE = numero_di_partizioni
      WHERE PR_KEY = 'DROP_PART_TO_CA_LG_SATELLITI_IMEL';
  END;
END;
/
```

The table exists and is pretty much empty, so it has not a partition more than 60 days ago.

This script continues to give me an error *inconsistent data types expected char got long*.
Precisely this error is in the first query, I've tried also to convert to Long but is not recommended and I did not achieved that.

Answer (score 1):

`*_TAB_PARTITIONS.HIGH_VALUE` is a long, which is extremely difficult to work with. You can't do anything with it in SQL. Fortunately, PL/SQL does have a built-in ability to convert it to a varchar2, simply by assignment.

```
DECLARE
  var_high_value_string varchar2(32767);
  var_high_value_date date;
BEGIN
  FOR rec_partition IN (SELECT partition_name,partition_position,high_value
                          FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS
                         WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CA_LG_SATELLITI_IMEL'
                           AND PARTITION_NAME LIKE 'SYS%'
                         ORDER BY partition_position)
  LOOP
     /* convert long to varchar2 by assignment */
     var_high_value_string := rec_partition.high_value;

     IF var_high_value_string != 'MAXVALUE'
     THEN
       /* evaluate string into a date with dynamic SQL */
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '||var_high_value_string||' FROM dual' INTO var_high_value_date;

       /* now check the date to see if it's old enough */

       IF var_high_value_date < SYSDATE - 60
       THEN
         -- do something.
       END IF;
     END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This will work for ranged partition tables on a single date column. If you have `LIST` partitions, or the datatype is something other than a date, or the partition key is multiple columns, all of that can be supported too but requires a bit more coding to address each situation and ensure you are assigning to the correctly typed variables.